# What animal is Marvin K Moony?

Tags: dr-seuss

What type of animal is Marvin K Mooney in Dr. Seuss's Marvin K Mooney Will You Please Go Now?

Some sort of Imaginary animal? Or a dog?

Comment: http://seuss.wikia.com/wiki/Marvin_K._Mooney

Answer (score 1):

He, like many (but not all) of Seuss's creatures and characters, is not really anything that specific: "[Marvin](http://seuss.wikia.com/wiki/Marvin_K._Mooney)'s a small dog-like creature that wears a lavender jumpsuit with a small bright yellow spot in the upper center."

Comment: You appear to be quoting from a [fan-written wiki](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6407/why-is-linking-st-questions-to-st-minutiae-rather-than-to-memory-alpha-better/6409#6409). If the mood took me, I could edit it to say that Marvin K Mooney is a horse and your answer would be worthless.

Comment: @Valorum Do you have anything to add that demonstrates the information I provided--Wiki or not--is incorrect..?

Comment: If I had something the disproved it, I'd post it as an answer. That still doesn't make your answer (wholly based on what wiki editor [Scarlovesseussbooks](http://seuss.wikia.com/wiki/Marvin_K._Mooney?action=history) wrote) a good one though. TheAsh already *guessed* that he's a dog. What makes you think that this wiki user has any more special insight than that?

Comment: The info I provided here--problematic and all--is all I could find including looking through the books on T.S. Geisel, his works, and the few articles/interviews I have on hand that may be relevant to this question (I'm no expert on Geisel--BTW).

As I stated in my answer, Seuss was not always specific or clear with his characters. So, this 'answer' is as good as it gets UNLESS you can provide something else.

Otherwise, sometimes you have to live with there not being a perfect answer or source.

Comment: *<mod deletes comments>* @Valorum You do have a point about wiki-sourced answers, but if your feedback isn't appreciated, it's better to **drop it** than continue arguing.